# DJango 1.7.4 issue with 'external_aliases'

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to do a simple query that works perfectly on all versions of django before the latest one (1.7.4). The query in question is below:

```
buddies = BuddyList.objects.filter(active=True).filter(user_id=4)
```

The error I get from django is below:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 691, in filter 
return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 705, in _filter_or_exclude 
clone = self._clone() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 952, in _clone 
query = self.query.clone() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 250, in clone 
obj.external_aliases = self.external_aliases.copy() 
AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'external_aliases'
```

Is there something i'm missing in the latest version? I tried reading the below:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py

https://github.com/jmoiron/johnny-cache/issues/29

What was changed with the `filter` for latest django version? It's a simple query that fails within the Django code...

The line 250 in the below file is what is causing issue:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/b626c289ccf9cc487f97d91c2a45cac096d9d0c7/django/db/models/sql/query.py

Comment: From where do you import this ``Users`` class? I can't see any such thing in the Django source code.

Comment: The `User` class here was an example. Basically doing a filter on a model. Ill change it so to not cause confusion.

Comment: OK, thanks. But there is still a problem with your question. A ``Model`` instance does not have any filter method! Is it ``buddies = Buddy.objects.filter(active=True)`` that you wanted to write? It would help a lot if you post the exact piece of code that causes the error you quote.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not allowed to post too much. I edited it again.

Comment: It's hard to believe you get an error from that query - is that the real query?

Comment: I had this issue with django-mptt. Looks like later version of Django has changed some stuff and updating django-mptt worked. In your case, update johnny-cache if it has newer release?

Answer (score 1):

In our scenario we encountered this while upgrading to django 1.8 from django 1.4.  Clearing the cache fixed it.